# Why does AutoField create the id field empty?

Tags: python, peewee

I am using the `create` method to create a record in a MySQL table:

```
class Interactions(BaseModel):
    id = AutoField(column_name='id')
    name = TextField(column_name='name')

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'interactions'

Interactions.create(name = 'Facebook')
```

The record is created, but the `id` is empty. How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have some issue in your table -- possibly this table was created beforehand or did not use an autoincrementing ID?

This example shows that AutoField is indeed autoincrementing, and that you overlooked something in your own code or db schema:

```
In [1]: from peewee import *

In [2]: db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

In [3]: class Reg(Model):
   ...:     id = AutoField(column_name='id')
   ...:     name = TextField(column_name='name')
   ...:     class Meta:
   ...:         database = db
   ...: 

In [4]: db.create_tables([Reg])

In [5]: Reg.create(name='r1')
Out[5]: <Reg: 1>

In [6]: for r in Reg.select():
   ...:     print(r.id, r.name)
   ...: 
1 r1
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. The type of the field `id` - `char(36)`.